# Parse local .CSV file with Firebase Cloud Function?

Tags: firebase, csv, parsing, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to implement some business logic on a cloud function where I pass a file (csv, pdf, or excel) as an argument and the Firebase Cloud Function would parse the file, depending on the file type.

**My Goal**

1. Drag and drop a file using [react-dropzone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropzone) **(Done)**
2. Pass that file with Redux Saga **(Done)**
3. Call Firebase Cloud Function with file as argument **(Done)**
4. Firebase Cloud Function parses CSV file and extracts data, which is an array of arrays. **(In Progress)**
5. Once parsed, the Firebase Cloud Function applies additional code to format the data in a JSON format.

**Questions:**

1. I'm trying .csv files first, but I am not sure how Cloud Functions work with `fs`. The library I am using is [csv-parse](https://csv.js.org/parse/api/stream/). Does `fs` work with Firebase Cloud Functions + Local files?
2. Are there native methods for Google Cloud Functions to parse .csv files? [createReadStream](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#createReadStream)?

I'm using [react-dropzone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropzone) to load the file, and it looks like this:

**File (From React-Dropzone):**

```
lastModified: 1359492652000
name: "FL_insurance_sample.csv"
path: "FL_insurance_sample.csv"
size: 4123652
type: "text/csv"
webkitRelativePath: ""
```

**Saga.js:**

```
// Redux Saga: Convert File To JSON
function* convertFileToJSON(action) {
  try {
    // Firebase Cloud Function: Covert File To JSON
    const extractedData = yield call(
      reduxSagaFirebase.functions.call,
      'convertFileToJSON',
      {
        file: action.file,
      },
    );

    // Firebase: Convert File To JSON Success
    yield put(convertFileToJSONSuccess(extractedData));
  }
  catch (error) {
    // Firebase: Convert File To JSON Error
    yield put(convertFileToJSONError(error));
  }
};
```

**Cloud Function**

```
// Imports: Dependencies
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
const parse = require('csv-parse');
const pdf = require('pdf-parse');
const fs = require('fs');

// Cloud Function: Convert File To JSON
exports.convertFileToJSON = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

  // CORS
  cors(request, response () => 

    // Check File Type: CSV
    if (request.type === 'csv') {
      // Parse CSV File

    }
    // Check File Type: PDF
    else if (request.type === 'pdf') {
      // Parse PDF File

    }
    // Check File Type: Excel
    else if (request.type === 'excel') {
      // Parse Excel File

    }
  );
});
```

Comment: I wonder, since `.csv` file size could be large (during runtime) - is it appropriate to process (parse & process) under a HTTP cloud function? I'd rather think of an approach, which involves the client (react web app) to upload the file to Firebase Storage, then a trigger to start the firebase function to read the file from storage bucket and parse and process further. This can be totally async and will not be a bottleneck for the user on the client (react web app). However, about `fs` FB function works just like any other node function & can access a _temporary_ local file system using `fs`